# How to explain the abstract syntax tree of chained comparison operations?

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

Comparison operators can be chained in python, so that for example `x < y < z` should give the result of `(x < y) and (y < z)`, except that `y` is guaranteed to be evaluated only once.

The abstract syntax tree of this operation looks like:

```
>>> ast.dump(ast.parse('0 < 1 < 2'), annotate_fields=0)
'Module([Expr(Compare(Num(0), [Lt(), Lt()], [Num(1), Num(2)]))])'
```

Pretty printed:

```
Module
  Expr
    Compare
      Num
      Lt
      Lt
      Num
      Num
```

But it seems to parse as something like `0 < < 1 2` and I'm not sure how to reconcile that with the logical result of something like `0 < 1 and 1 < 2`.

How can the ast for chained comparisons be explained?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reasoning behind this is actually mentioned in the [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html) docs

> ```
> -- need sequences for compare to distinguish between
> -- x < 4 < 3 and (x < 4) < 3
> | Compare(expr left, cmpop* ops, expr* comparators)
> ```

If it were evaluated as two separate compares, like this

```
Module(Expr(Compare(Compare(Num(0), [Lt()], [Num(1)]), [Lt()], [Num(2)]))])
```

Then it's actually comparing the boolean *result* of the first comparison with the integer in the second comparison.

Something like this wouldn't work

```
-5 < -4 < -3
```

Because it would be evaluated as

```
(-5 < -4) < -3
```

Which evaluates as

```
1 < -3
```

So instead, it's dealt with as a single expression.  A python implementation of the `Compare` operation would look something like this

```
def Compare(left, ops, comparators):
    if not ops[0](left, comparators[0]):
        return False

    for i, comparator in enumerate(comparators[1:], start=1):
        if not ops[i](comparators[i-1], comparator):
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: I would write the `Compare()` procedure a little differently. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40431833/6394138).

Answer (score 3):

I think that you need to think of it as a short-circuiting pipeline of things to do.  e.g. if you `zip` the `ops` with the `comparators`, and then work on them one at a time:

```
result = left
for op, comparator in zip(ops, comparators):
    result = result and evaluate(result, op, comparator)
    if not result:
        break
```

Obviously, I'm leaving a bunch to the imagination here ... e.g. I didn't define `evaluate`.  However, it's a pretty hard thing to define since we don't know what the comparator expression looks like in the general case.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to complement [Brendan Abel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40431649/6394138) with my version of the `Compare()` function, which IMHO is a little easier to comprehend:

```
def Compare(left, ops, comparators):
    for x, op, y in zip([left] + comparators[:-1], ops, comparators):
        if not op(x, y):
            return False
    return True
```