# Python print with < symbol

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why is `print(0<0<2)` false?
Which does it compute first `0<0` and then `false<2` or the entire statement together?

Also, why is `print(False<2)` True?

Also, `print(False<True)` True?

Comment: Please prefer asking a single question per question. When there's 3 questions in one post, it can't be effectively deduplicated, and you can't easily accept a single answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is `print(0<0<2)` false?

wim linked a really interesting post that answers this question ( [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40431452/how-to-explain-the-abstract-syntax-tree-of-chained-comparison-operations) )

> why is `print(False<2)` True?

Because the `<` operator evaluates `False` as 0 in this specific circumstance

> [Why is] `print(False<True)` True?

Because `False` is evaluated as 0 and `True` is evaluated as 1. Therefor `0<1` is true

Comment: Note the "Answer Well-Asked Questions" section of [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), particularly the "uniquely identify the problem" phrase in the first bullet point (note: singular!), in combination with the one-question-to-a-question rules [cited by that other guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1899640/that-other-guy).

Comment: Not quite. `False` *is* 0, in the sense that `bool` is a subtype of `int`.